# "ne paelici suspectaretur" (Tacitus)

Tags: classical-latin, meaning, dative

Tacitus, *Annales* 4.3:

> pellit domo Seianus uxorem Apicatam, ex qua tres liberos genuerat, **ne paelici suspectaretur**.

The translation on [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0077%3Abook%3D4%3Achapter%3D3) (Church and Brodribb) gives:

> Sejanus, **to avert his mistress's jealousy**, divorced his wife Apicata, by whom he had had three children.

How does *ne paelici suspectaretur* mean *to avert his mistress's jealousy*?

*Ne suspectaretur* is easy: "lest he should be suspected". *Paelici* is a dative of *paelex* "mistress". But I'm not seeing what a dative could be doing in this clause.

Apparently, too, there's an alternate reading of this phrase: L&S under *[suspecto](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsuspecto1)* quote this as *ne pellici suspectaretur*, with a passive infinitive of *pellicio* "allure, entice". It would then mean "lest he be suspected of being enticed". This at least works grammatically, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean.

What's going on with this phrase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be read as a **dativus auctoris**. It should then be translated thus:

> lest he should be suspected **by his mistress** / be suspect **to his mistress**

Common in gerundive constructions *(hostis **nobis** vincendus est)*, the dativus auctoris is also occasionally used with other passive verbs; it is then most common with past participles (*mihi cognitum est*: "it is known by me" or "it is known to me"). It indicates the person by whom something is done. Especially with verbs expressing a judgement, it is somewhat similar to the ordinary dative of *videtur mihi* "it seems to me" etc. [Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=suspecto%232&filter=CUTF8) say the verb *suspectaretur* in this particular quotation is passive, i.e. not from the deponent verb *suspector*.

According to Kühner–Stegmann¹, this dativus auctoris was only used in the perfect and with a personal pronoun in older Latin (pace their own Accius example, see below); but Cicero and various later authors used it with other passive forms and substantive nouns, too. K.–S. also mention Tacitus specifically.

In poetry, it is (especially) used by the Augustan poets, even non metri causa. They say the construction is originally Latin, but was extended under Greek influence (after all, the agent in a passive construction is normally expressed by a dative in Greek).

Here follow a few examples taken from K.–S. and Gildersleeve:

Accius, *Tragoediae* 284:

> DIOMEDES:
>    Ergo me Argos referam, nam hic sum gnobilis
>     ne **cui** cognoscar **noto**.

"Then I will go back to Argos, for here I am notable, lest I be recognised by someone I know."

---

Cicero, *Tusculanae Disputationes* 5.68.4:

> "Sumatur...**nobis** quidam praestans vir..."

"Let us assume an excellent man..."

---

Tacitus, *Annales* 2.50.13:

> ... ut exemplo maiorum **propinquis suis** ultra ducentesimum lapidem removeretur suasit.

" ...he suggested that, according to ancient custom, she should be removed by her next of kin beyond the two-hundredth milestone."

---

Tacitus, *Annales* 12.1.1:

> Aelia Paetina...**Narcisso** fovebatur.

"Aelia Paetina was favoured by Narcissus."

---

The past participle or adjective *suspectus* is often used with a dative, which may also have influenced Tacitus to use the dativus auctoris with a passive imperfect (as in the quotation in question). Two examples with *suspectus*:

Sallustius, *Bellum Iugurthinum* 70.1.1:

> Bomilcar...suspectus **regi** et ipse eum suspiciens novas res cupere...

"Bomilcar, suspected by the King [or: suspect to the King], and himself suspecting the King, desired a change of power..."

---

Tacitus, Annales 14.44.10:

> Suspecta **maioribus nostris** fuerunt ingenia servorum...

"To our ancestors, the temper of their slaves was suspect..."

---

---

¹) Satzlehre vol. I (1912), §76 8d, p. 324:

[image]

Comment: I think that the following disjunction ("or") can be a bit misleading when giving the translation of _mihi cognitum est_  (cf. your translations, the typical ones, "it is known by me" or "it is known to me"). I think that Latin speakers did distinguish between agent by-phrases and dative "agents". E.g., cf. the parallelism between _Caesar equitatum coactum habebat_ (Caes. _BG_ 1.15) and _**Caesari** equitatus coactus erat_. Crucially, the parallelism with _habere_ does **not** hold for ablative agents: cf. _**A Caesare** equitatus coactus erat_.

Comment: Similarly, _**Mihi** deliberatum est_ and _**A me** deliberatum est_ have different (linguistic) meanings. The former is nicely translated in Romance by using the verb HAVE (e.g., Cat. 'tenir'): cf. "Ho tinc decidit" (lit. 'I have this decided') and "Això {ha estat/fou} decidit per mi" (lit. 'This {has been/was} decided by me'), respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It can be useful to consult the relevant commentary made by A. J. Woodman (2018). *The Annals of Tacitus (Book IV)*. Series: *Cambridge Classical Texts and Commentaries* (vol. 58). Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press.

Here is the relevant quote on **page 87**:

"It is unclear whether *paelici* is dative of agent (cf. 2.50.3n) or dative of the person concerned (as in *alicui suspectus esse*); either way, the use of the verb to mean 'to suspect, be suspicious of' seems to have been introduced by Tacitus (see *OLD 2*)".

According to Woodman, notice then that TWO interpretations are possible here, whereby the two translations provided by Cerberus (cf. *lest he should be suspected by his mistress / be suspect to his mistress*) correspond to TWO different (descriptive) linguistic analyses: i.e., according to Woodman, only the former translation corresponds to the dative of agent reading.

---

The expression *ne paelici suspectaretur* is also briefly commented on in the following book: Garrett G. Fagan & Paul Murgatroyd (2010). *From Augustus to Nero: An Intermediate Latin Reader*. Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press.

Here is the relevant quote on page **60**:

"*paelici* is dative of agent. Sejanus did not want his mistress Livilla to have suspicions about his feelings for her, so he got rid of his wife".

Comment: In general, agent and experiencer can be distinguished. As to whether the distinction can be made in this particular praedicate frame (*suspectaretur*), I'm open to it, but I am not yet convinced either way; the fact that the phrase can be translated in different ways is not proof to me. // I think the Aktionsart is very important and must be considered. // Thematic roles interest me very much. // I wasn't sure how the two types of constructions in your comments corresponded to the two thematic roles in the example.

Comment: P.S. I found this page in an open tab in my browser from long ago (I tend to hoard tabs...); it seems I never got around to replying. I always read your posts and comments with great interest, even though I'm not always good at replying!