# Shouldn't this *illis* be in the genitive *illorum* in here?

Tags: case

In the famous Caesar's sentence:

> *Perfacile factu esse illis probat conata perficere, propterea quod ipse suae civitatis imperium obtenturus esset: non esse dubium quin totius galliae plurimum helvetii possent: se suis copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum (esse), confirmat. *

The first *illis* in *Perfacile factu esse illis probat* is ok and easy. The problem is with the *illis* on ***se suis copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum (esse), confirmat.***

To me, that second one shouldn't be on ablative nor on dative but on genitive. Can somebody please make sense of whatever case it is in that sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sense, [*concilio*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/concilio) means "gain" or "win over," and a very common construction (see meaning I.B.1.β) is *conciliare aliquem* [acc.] *alicui* [dat.], i.e. "to win over something [acc.] for someone [dat.]."

Breaking down your sentence, which uses indirect discourse:

```
1. confirmat                              verb of main clause
2.     se conciliaturum [esse]            ACI: indirect discourse
3.         suis copiis suoque exercitu    ablative of means
4.         regna                          accusative direct object of conciliare
5.         illis                          dative with conciliare
```

Putting it all together:

> [1] He assures [them] [2] that he will win over [3] with his troops and with his army [4] the royal powers [5] for them.

Comment: Nice & clear answer! Cf. the same dative associated to a gerundival form of this verb: _ad eorum voluntatem mihi conciliandam maximo te mihi usui fore video_  (Cic. _Att._ 1.2). One could say that _mihi_ is a "dative of agent" in this gerundival context, but it is not. Here _mihi_ is, as you rightly note, the beneficiary dative argument selected by the verb. (Context of the discussion: (typical) "datives of agent" cannot depend on the gerundive form. Cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/can-a-dative-of-agent-appear-in-an-ablative-absolute-construction-and-more-g/21220#21220 ).